# Rails + ActiveRecord: comparing dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, datetime, activerecord

I have a document that has been generated, say, on `2017-10-03 15:02:47`.

Then I have this Rails/SQL query (it doesn't matter if I run it through Rails or straight through the SQL console, the results are the same):

```
SELECT * FROM table where needed_column <= '2017-10-03';
```

This query would not return me the document that has been generated on `2017-10-03 15:02:47`. If I do run, though, this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table where needed_column <= '2017-10-03 23:59:59';
```

Then I get the needed document (generated on `2017-10-03 15:02:47`).

To solve this issue, I can manually add the time to the query (`23:59:59`), but it's not a very elegant solution.

I am using Rails 5, AR, PostgreSQL - is there a better way to solve this problem than to manually add the time stamp to the query?

Thank you

Comment: try to use "end_of_day" eg:  Time.now.end_of_day gives Mon Oct 09 23:59:59 UTC 2017

Comment: I think that's because 2017-10-03 15:02:47 is considered to be greater than just 2017-10-03. You could use SELECT * FROM table where needed_column < '2017-10-04';

Comment: try this query SELECT * FROM table where needed_column <= Date '2017-10-03';

Answer (score 4):

Your `needed_column` is probably saving timestamps (Date and Time). As you already figured it out you need to compare it with another timestamp or cast `needed_column` using `::date`

```
Model.where("needed_column::date <= '2017-10-03'")
```

This will generate:

```
SELECT table.* FROM table WHERE (needed_column::date <= '2017-10-03')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in Rails:-

```
Model.where(needed_column: [Time.now.at_beginning_of_day, Time.now.end_of_day])
```

Or as sql query:-

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE needed_column BETWEEN '2017-10-09 00:00:00 UTC' AND '2017-10-09 23:59:59 UTC'
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. I used Date.commercial which does not create a DateTime object (rather a date object). My where clause was failing because of that. The beginning_of_day and end_of_day fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work today (Aug 2021). What does work is ```[Time.now.at_beginning_of_day.. Time.now.end_of_day]```